# How do I properly cancel pending runnable and keep the custom views visible whilst user is interacting with them?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I have made a custom video player, and it's working mostly fine. However, there is a bug that I want to get rid of. I could use some help figuring out what I'm doing wrong. For more context, I am setting a `postDelay Runnable` to hide the view after 3 seconds, which is working. I, however, **want to be able to cancel that runnable if the user keeps interacting with the video view and its options**. Here is the code, and what I have tried so far is to remove pending callbacks and messages, which, is not responding as expected, as the views keep disappearing after the 3 seconds that I set earlier: 
**NB: I shared the whole class to give you a more clear context of my implementation**

```
package consumer.app.co.za.rain.clean.ui.view.custom.doityourselfvideoplayer

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.Context
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.Looper
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.MotionEvent
import android.view.View
import android.widget.FrameLayout
import android.widget.SeekBar
import consumer.app.co.za.rain.R
import consumer.app.co.za.rain.databinding.MiniScreenVideoPlayerLayoutBinding

@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
class VideoPlayerMiniScreen @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : FrameLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    /** Initialize global/class variables */
    private val binding = MiniScreenVideoPlayerLayoutBinding.inflate(
        LayoutInflater.from(context),
        this,
        true
    )

    private var seekBarTracking = false
    private val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())

    private val updateProgressRunnable = object : Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            if (!seekBarTracking && binding.vvDoItYourself.isPlaying) {
                val currentPosition = binding.vvDoItYourself.currentPosition
                binding.seekBarDoItYourself.progress = currentPosition
            }
            handler.postDelayed(this, 16)
        }
    }

    init {
        with(binding) {

            /** Set up video player widgets */
            videoOptionsDoItYourself.apply {
                visibility = VISIBLE
                z = 2F
            }
            ivPlayPause.apply {
                alpha = 1F
                visibility = GONE
                z = 2F
            }

            val hideViewRunnable = Runnable {
                hideView(videoOptionsDoItYourself)
            }

            /** Set up video player */
            vvDoItYourself.run {

                z = 1F

                setOnTouchListener { _, event ->
                    when (event.action) {
                        MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                            /** Remove the pending post of setViewToDisappear callback */
                            cancelSetViewToDisappear(hideViewRunnable)

                            Log.d("DIY", "Touched Down")

                            if (ivPlayPause.visibility == VISIBLE) togglePlayPause()
                            else {

                                Log.d("DIY", "Released")
                                showView(ivPlayPause)
                                showView(videoOptionsDoItYourself)
                            }
                        }
                        MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                            setViewToDisappear(ivPlayPause)
                            setViewToDisappear(videoOptionsDoItYourself)
                        }
                    }
                    true
                }

                setOnPreparedListener { mediaPlayer ->
                    seekBarDoItYourself.max = mediaPlayer.duration

                    /** Start in a stale state */
                    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying) mediaPlayer.stop()

                    mediaPlayer.setOnSeekCompleteListener {
                        val currentPosition = mediaPlayer.currentPosition
                        seekBarDoItYourself.progress = currentPosition
                    }

                    /** Update Progress Bar in real-time */
                    handler.post(updateProgressRunnable)
                }

                setOnCompletionListener { mediaPlayer ->
                    ivPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.baseline_play_arrow_24)
                    showView(ivPlayPause)
                    seekBarDoItYourself.progress = 0
                    mediaPlayer.seekTo(0)
                    handler.removeCallbacks(updateProgressRunnable)
                }
            }

            ivPlayPause.setOnClickListener {
                togglePlayPause()
            }

            seekBarDoItYourself.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object :
                SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
                override fun onProgressChanged(
                    seekBar: SeekBar?,
                    progress: Int,
                    fromUser: Boolean
                ) {
                    // Update the seek bar's progress as the video plays
                    if (!seekBarTracking) {
                        if (vvDoItYourself.isPlaying) {
                            val currentPosition = vvDoItYourself.currentPosition
                            seekBarDoItYourself.progress = currentPosition
                        }
                    }

                    // Update the video's position to the seek bar's progress
                    if (fromUser) {
                        vvDoItYourself.seekTo(progress)
                        seekBarDoItYourself.progress = progress
                    }
                }

                override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {
                    seekBarTracking = true
                }

                override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {
                    seekBarTracking = false
                    seekBar?.let {
                        val progress = it.progress
                        vvDoItYourself.seekTo(progress)
                    }
                }
            })
        }


    }

    fun setVideoURI(uri: Uri) {
        binding.vvDoItYourself.setVideoURI(uri)
    }

    private fun togglePlayPause() {
        with(binding) {
            if (!vvDoItYourself.isPlaying) {
                ivPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.baseline_pause_24)
                vvDoItYourself.start()
            } else {
                ivPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.baseline_play_arrow_24)
                vvDoItYourself.pause()
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set to be called when controls are hidden
     */
    private fun showView(view: View) {
        view.run {
            visibility = VISIBLE
            alpha = 0F
            animate().alpha(1F).setDuration(500).withEndAction {

            }.start()
        }
    }

    private fun hideView(view: View) {
        view.run {
            alpha = 1F
            animate().alpha(0F).setDuration(500).withEndAction {
                view.visibility = GONE
            }.start()
        }
    }

    fun setViewToDisappear(view: View) {
        val hideViewRunnable = Runnable {
            hideView(view)
        }
        handler.postDelayed(hideViewRunnable, 3000)
    }

    fun cancelSetViewToDisappear(runnable: Runnable) {
        handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(runnable)
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to cancel your pending `Runnable`, you have to pass *that specific `Runnable` object* to the *remove callbacks* call. Right now, when you post the Runnable, you're not keeping a reference to it:

```
fun setViewToDisappear(view: View) {
    // you're only storing this in a variable local to the function
    val hideViewRunnable = Runnable { hideView(view) }
    handler.postDelayed(hideViewRunnable, 3000)
}
```

And the one you're trying to cancel is a *different* Runnable (that happens to have the same name), which is local to the `init` block (and captured by the touch listener closure - i.e. you referred to it in the lambda, so that block has a reference to it)

```
// in the init block

// this is a local variable 
val hideViewRunnable = Runnable { hideView(videoOptionsDoItYourself) }

...

// in the touch listener defined in the init block
cancelSetViewToDisappear(hideViewRunnable)
```

So you're passing a different `Runnable` instance to your cancel function.

---

You have two options - probably the easiest is just to make `hideViewRunnable` a top-level variable, so `setViewToDisappear` can reference it instead of having to create a new instance. That way you just post and cancel the same `Runnable`.

Another option is to use the `Handler` *post* and *remove* functions that take a *token* parameter - that can be anything, it's just a shared object that lets you group stuff together by using the same token object, and you can easily cancel anything that uses the same token. Same idea as re-using the same Runnable, except you're using a shared token object to identify them instead